# Error on "pip install --upgrade distribute"

Tags: python, pip, homebrew, easy-install

Installed python via homebrew as such:

```
brew install python --universal --framework
```

Followed the instructions over at https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/wiki/Homebrew-and-Python to install pip and upgrade distribute.  pip install appeared to go fine, but whenever I try to use pip to upgrade distribute or install virtualenv as such

```
pip install --upgrade distribute
```

or

```
pip install virtualenv
```

I get the following error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "/usr/local/bin/pip", line
>   5, in 
>       from pkg_resources import load_entry_point   File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources.py",
>   line 2603, in 
>       working_set.require(**requires**)   File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources.py",
>   line 666, in require
>       needed = self.resolve(parse_requirements(requirements))   File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources.py",
>   line 565, in resolve
>       raise DistributionNotFound(req)  # XXX put more info here pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: pip==1.0.2

Not proficient enough in python to know what is going on here so if anyone knows how to correct this it would be appreciated.

My $PATH looks like this:

> /Users/wg/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@rails3_2/bin:/Users/wg/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@global/bin:/Users/wg/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/bin:/Users/wg/.rvm/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/share/python:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11/bin:/usr/local/git/bin

... and when I run `which pip` I get `/usr/local/bin/pip` (not sure if this is the problem and if so, what to do to get it to use the right version of pip).

EDIT:

Wanted to include that I'm running Lion OS 10.7 with the latest build of XCode and the Command utilities installed.  Also, don't know if this helps, but I thought I'd include the results of running "which easy_install" as well ... returns:

> /usr/local/share/python/easy_install

Not sure if that is perhaps related as well.

---

Thanks much!

Answer (score 4):

I practice, I find running

```
pip install --upgrade setuptools
```

before

```
pip install --upgrade distribute
pip install --upgrade pip
```

solves my problem when running `pip install --upgrade distribute`.